# Does the idiom "in lieu of" for "instead of" sound legalese or affected in modern day AmE

Tags: idioms, american-english, word-usage

I once came across the idiomatic "in lieu of" in some bilingual dictionary I can't seem to put my hands on anymore, but I remember pretty well the phrase being defined as an Americanism.

And so, I wish you could tell if "in lieu of" is safe to use instead of "instead of" in everyday speech and writing. Or does it sound sort of legalese or stilted for the most common prose?

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+lieu+of

E.g.

More and more health conscious consumers are becoming aware of the value of raw milk and raw milk products in lieu of pasteurized milk and milk products. [source](http://www.naturalnews.com/035716_raw_milk_legal_directory.html)

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: As a speaker of Canadian English, the phrase *in lieu of* sounds perfectly normal.  I would, however, only use it in certain contexts.  To me, *instead of going to the pool, we went to the lake* implies that going to the pool was an option, but we preferred the lake, whereas *in lieu of going to the pool, we went to the lake* implies that, though we usually go to the pool, we chose the lake instead.

Comment: Could you please use AmE instead of AE when referring to American English. It's easily confused with Australian English.

Comment: @Mitch: Or just say "in America". I hate needless abbreviations!! *growls*

Comment: @Cerberus Not everyone in America (even allowing you to take the name of two entire continents for a single country) speaks AmE.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: There will always be subtle distinctions, but this one does not seem relevant. The meaning is clear.

Comment: The most common usage in AmE is in funeral announcements.  *In lieu of flowers, donations can be made to XYZ.*

Comment: I am intrigued because I would feel self conscious saying or writing _in lieu of_, but I would not be bothered if someone else did.

Comment: ***"instead of"*** works as an acceptable replacement for "in lieu of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'lieu' is a good word. I use it myself from time to time in communications, specifically in letters. Using it expands our vocabulary benefiting not only the user but the receivers as well. A dictionary I reviewed provides the following usages: 'lieu' noun-single [MF, from Latin locus---more at stall]: place, stead. e.g. (the mumbling cant that... the characters employ in lieu of English--John McCarten); "rendered three days work in lieu of rent--G.G. Coulton"; "striking out the words, "one year" and inserting in lieu thereof the words "six months"---U.S. Code."

> Stall, noun-single, To set up, make ready, send.

Source: Webster's Third New International Dictionary, G&C Merriam Co. Publishers, Springfield, Mass. USA, 1968

Its acceptable then to use it for legalese and everyday American English.

Answer (score -3):

You are better off using the latter. In lieu of does sound prissy and went out with the ark as far as day-to-day conversations are concerned. It's not any different from trying to use thou in a conversation. Even most of the document writers now a days, are advised to do away with words that had had their origin from other languages. For instance per annum is replaced by the phrases per year or annually now a days. So, unless you plan on showing off you might want to stick with instead of or in place of.

Comment: Doing away with words that have their origins in other languages would reduce English to a useless stub of a semi-language. I think you mean words that are _perceivable_ and _perceived_ as being still foreign.

Comment: Yes, that's is what I meant. :)

Comment: It isn't about "doing away" deliberately versus a natural progression of a language. I guess this is how a language evolves over a period of time. Words that are slang now may eventually become mainstream and mainstream words may become archaic. Words such as "thou" are as relevant and a part of English as "you", albeit unused.